# Page can not be updated and disappeared in "show all page"

Tags: pages

I have a strange problem now.

Today I am editing a very old page. I restored to old version and also modified something. Suddenly I found I can never update that page. Then I tried set it pending then set back to published. The "no update" issue still there. What is worst is I can not find it in "page List".

As you can see from the picture:
All(3): only show 2
When I click Pending(1): No page found
I have right to approve page as I am the only user.

That page can only be found by clicking "edit this page" link when browse it as a reader.

[image: Only show 2 pages]

[image: The pending 1 page can never be shown!]

Comment: Try copying the missing page to a new page. Does the new page show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to repair your database. To do it, please read [this answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8570285/195824).

If repairing database didn't worked, you can try to update the post status manually.

1. Connect to your database
2. Find the page in the wp_posts table (you can find it through the post_title field)
3. Update the record running a script like this one:

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'publish' WHERE ID = YOUR_PAGE_ID